# Is it possible to set a limit to the values that can be chosen using jqPlots dragable?

Tags: jquery, jqplot

Would it be possible to set an upper limit to the values that can be chosen when using Dragable in jqPlot? For instance that the maximum y-value that can be chosen is 10 (with no minimum limit) for all points in the series?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Set max attributes.

See this: http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/jqplot-core-js.html#Axis.max